# Codeigniter Return value

Tags: php, codeigniter, boolean, return

I am new to Codeigniter and PHP..

while doing some operations i have some doubts ,especially in the database libraries .

```
$get = "select filed_1 from tbl_ctc where ctc=?";
$get = $this->db->query($get,array($ctc_n));

if ($get)
{

 //do some operations 
}
else
{
 //do some another operations 

}
```

What will be the return value of $get if it is success ?

Expecting opinion & suggestion [downvotes too]

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What "opinions and suggestions" do you expect?

The query() method returns a **result object** when you use *read* queries (like a select), while with *write* queries (like an insert or update) it returns TRUE or FALSE.

In case of a SELECT, i.e., you might want to check if it has any result:

```
$query = $this->db->query($select_query);
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{}
```

While, in case of an INSERT for ex.:

```
$query = $this->db->query($insert_query);
if($query)   // or if(FALSE !== $query)
{}
else
{}
```

Note that if you are using Active Record, you'll have the `result()` / `row()` and `result_array()` / `row_array()` methods that will return either a full object/array or an empty one, so you'll need to check for those values instead.

Comment: Thank you,this is what i exactly expected answer,but what will return if the query failed in some cases[in select queries]....

Comment: "opinions and suggestions" - about coding practices ,beginner mistakes ,good links to sources etc

Comment: Well, I cannot test right now, but simply var_dump() the returned value of a failing query (if you can create it somehow).I suspect an empty object or a FALSE, but never tried that.

Answer (score 1):

The result will be an object. You have to go one step further to get the expected value, e.g.

```
$get = $this->db->query($get,array($ctc_n));
$res = $get->result_array();

echo $res[0]['filed_1'];
```

See [Active Record Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) and [examples](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html) from the user guide for further reference.

Comment: yeah..sure i can use `row_array` too ,but i have trouble with that IF loop can i do like this `if ($get)` ??

Comment: @DileepDil -- If you just want to see if a record(s) has been returned, you could use `if ($get->num_rows() > 0) {}`

Comment: Okkey,but i think that it will return `FALSE` if the query failed ,so can i use `if($get != FALSE)` ?? also what about insert functionality ??

Comment: What do you mean if the query failed? If no records were found, `if ($get) {}` will still return as `true`...it's not a reliable way of checking if there has been a result or not. As for insert functionality, you can use `if ($this->db->insert('yourtable', $data)) {}`, which will return `true` if the query was successful.

Comment: I am not saying about what is returned through the query,i just want to know that the Query operation is success or failed ,

Comment: Like I said, _success_ = result is returned. _Failed_ = no result. `if ($get) {}` will return `true` for both of those scenarios.